# Preserving line breaks from text area before or after php filter sanitize

Tags: php, line-breaks, sanitize

Im having trouble understanding how to go about this.
I have content in a  tag which i want to save in a database.
Im using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING  to escape XSS attacks however its getting rid of the line breaks in my textarea content.

Im wondering how do i go about sanitizing my content (Preventing XSS risk) but yet keeping the breaks so i can add it to my database and pull it from the database with the breaks intact

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it really getting rid of the linebreaks? They won't show up if you output them directly to the page; you'll need to use [`nl2br`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` should not strip line breaks (or more accurately CRLF sequences, since the data comes from a textarea) unless you also specify `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` - are you doing this? If you are (and you actually need to), simply run `str_replace("\r\n", '%SomePlaceholderOfYourChoosing%', $str);` before the `filter_var()` and `str_replace('%SomePlaceholderOfYourChoosing%', "\r\n", $str);` after - it's hacky but it will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all linebreaks its HTML entity `&#x000A;` - which will be displayed as a linebreak when output as HMTL. You'll have to return them back to the original linebreaks if you want readable contents in the database however.